# iterar 2 array de objetos y no mostrar los repetidos

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos que estoy guardando en un array los objetos que tengan los elementos de `fl_grpTIP` diferentes, en este caso sería el 1 y 2.

```js
let obj = [
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 0.0,
    fl_codfrmt: '',
    fl_grpfrmt: '0',
    fl_descri2: '',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_descri1: '',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
  },
 {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 0.0,
    fl_grpfrmt: '2',
    fl_codfrmt: '00001',
    fl_descri2: '',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_descri1: '',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_descri1: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Comerciales Terceros',
    fl_descri2: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Comerciales Terceros',
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    dl_SALDO: 52694.06,
    fl_codfrmt: '10003',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_grpTIP: '2',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 100.0,
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    fl_codfrmt: '10006',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
    fl_descri2: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Diversas Terceros',
    fl_descri1: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Diversas Terceros',
  },
  {
    dl_SALDO: 42281.0,
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_codfrmt: '10009',
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    fl_descri1: 'Inventarios',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_descri2: 'Inventarios',
    fl_grpTIP: '2',
  },
];

let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = [];

obj.forEach(ele => {
  if (ele.fl_grpTIP === '1') {
    arr1.push(ele);
  }
  if (ele.fl_grpTIP === '2') {
    arr2.push(ele);
  }
});

let result = [];

result.push(arr1, arr2);

console.log(result)
```

Y lo que necesito es tener los saldos del primer array y del segundo array, osea, los valores del elemento `dl_SALDO` de cada array. intenté hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let obj = [
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 0.0,
    fl_codfrmt: '',
    fl_grpfrmt: '0',
    fl_descri2: '',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_descri1: '',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 0.0,
    fl_grpfrmt: '2',
    fl_codfrmt: '00001',
    fl_descri2: '',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_descri1: '',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_descri1: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Comerciales Terceros',
    fl_descri2: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Comerciales Terceros',
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    dl_SALDO: 52694.06,
    fl_codfrmt: '10003',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_grpTIP: '2',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 100.0,
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    fl_codfrmt: '10006',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
    fl_descri2: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Diversas Terceros',
    fl_descri1: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Diversas Terceros',
  },
  {
    dl_SALDO: 42281.0,
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_codfrmt: '10009',
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    fl_descri1: 'Inventarios',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_descri2: 'Inventarios',
    fl_grpTIP: '2',
  },
];

let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = [];

obj.forEach(ele => {
  if (ele.fl_grpTIP === '1') {
    arr1.push(ele);
  }
  if (ele.fl_grpTIP === '2') {
    arr2.push(ele);
  }
});

let result = [];

result.push(arr1, arr2);

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  console.log(result[0][i].dl_SALDO);
  for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    console.log(result[1][j].dl_SALDO);
  }
}
```

Pero mi resultado es el siguiente:

```
// 0
// 52694.06
// 42281
// 0
// 52694.06
// 42281
// 100
// 52694.06
// 42281
```

Y mi resultado esperado es el siguiente:

```
// 0
// 0
// 100
// 52694.06
// 42281
```

En donde los 3 primeros numeros del resultado esperado son los saldos del primer array, y los otros 2 numeros son los saldos del segundo array, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, filtrar cada array para eliminar duplicados y luego los concatenas:

```
let result = [];
arr1 = arr1.filter((item,
            index) => arr1.indexOf(item) === index);

arr2 = arr2.filter((item,
            index) => arr2.indexOf(item) === index);

result = arr1.concat(arr2);

  for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
    console.log(result[j].dl_SALDO);
}
```

Resultado:

```
0
0
100
52694.06
42281
```

En base a tu comentario te dejo otra opcion, basicamente lo que hago es ver cual array es mas grande y usar un solo for chequeando si en esa posicion es o no undefined:

```
let obj = [
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 0.0,
    fl_codfrmt: '',
    fl_grpfrmt: '0',
    fl_descri2: '',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_descri1: '',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 0.0,
    fl_grpfrmt: '2',
    fl_codfrmt: '00001',
    fl_descri2: '',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_descri1: '',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_descri1: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Comerciales Terceros',
    fl_descri2: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Comerciales Terceros',
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    dl_SALDO: 52694.06,
    fl_codfrmt: '10003',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_grpTIP: '2',
  },
  {
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    dl_SALDO: 100.0,
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    fl_codfrmt: '10006',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_grpTIP: '1',
    fl_descri2: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Diversas Terceros',
    fl_descri1: 'Cuentas por Cobrar Diversas Terceros',
  },
  {
    dl_SALDO: 42281.0,
    TITULO: 'ACTIVOS',
    fl_codfrmt: '10009',
    fl_grpfrmt: '1',
    fl_descri1: 'Inventarios',
    ELEMENTO: 'ACTIVO CORRIENTE',
    fl_descri2: 'Inventarios',
    fl_grpTIP: '2',
  },
];

let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = [];

obj.forEach(ele => {
  if (ele.fl_grpTIP === '1') {
    arr1.push(ele);
  }
  if (ele.fl_grpTIP === '2') {
    arr2.push(ele);
  }
});

let result = [];

result.push(arr1, arr2);

let length = arr1.length >= arr2.length ? arr1.length : arr2.length;

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if(typeof result[0][i] !== 'undefined')
      console.log(result[0][i].dl_SALDO);
    if(typeof result[1][i]!== 'undefined')
      console.log(result[1][i].dl_SALDO);
}
```

Resultado:

```
0
52694.06
0
42281
100
```

Comment: Hola amigo muy buenas lo que pasa es que en tu filter esta obviando mi condicion ele.fl_grpTIP === '1' o '2'  y el concat lo que hace es inicializar mi array como estaba antes del push

Comment: Modifique la respuesta, espero te sirva. Saludos.